# Dynamic ldap with spring security in grails

Tags: grails, spring-security, ldap

I am writing a grails application using the spring security plugin and would like to use the spring ldap plugin. I need to be able to alter the ldap settings though without re-compiling, so I do not believe I can set this in the config file. I have gotten this to work with different ldap plugins, but they don't play as nice with spring security which I like. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One convenient option might be to use an external config file (described [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#configExternalized) in the Grails docs).

You might, for example, create a separate `custom-ldap-settings.properties` file containing your Spring Security / LDAP configuration.  A partial sample:

```
...
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.context.server = ldap://<AD Domain IP Address>
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.search.base = ou=Accounts,dc=domain,dc=com
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.search.filter = (AccountName={0})
...
```

You can then place this `.properties` file in your classpath for deployment, and then merge these settings into your main config in `Config.groovy`:

```
grails.config.locations = [ "classpath:custom-ldap-settings.properties" ]
```

You can make changes to this external `.properties` file without recompiling or rebuilding your .war file.  After updating settings in your `properties` file, all you would need to do is restart your application or container (ie. Apache Tomcat).

Comment: This answer is partially what I wanted. This had not been working for me as I had a space after classpath I believe and everything broke. It is possible to make it work without even needing an apache restart. I ended up using the groovy ldap library and this lets you poll ldap every time you are authenticating. Probably not as fast. But just so anyone knows.